# Analytical function describing transition from stretched exponential to power law

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

The results of a simulation I have launched look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We6Xt.png)
My goal is to find an analytical fit of these functions. As it can be seen, the curve labeled with probability $p = 1.0$ "seems" a **stretched exponential** function, while decreasing the probability, the curve looks more like a **power law**. Does anyone know an analytical function which evolves from a stretched exponential to a power law changing its parameters?
Of course, if you believe it is not a stretched exponential evolving to a power law, you can suggest your approach.